# Data insertion fails in Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

### My configuration

Cluster with two nodes:

- Node 1:
  Hardware: Intel Xeon 2.83 GHz (4 cores), 24GB RAM, Dell VIRTUAL DISK SCSI 500GB
  System: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
  Java version: 7 update 4 x64
  Apache Cassandra version: 1.1.1
- Node 2:
  Hardware: Intel Xeon 2.83 GHz (4 cores), 8GB RAM, Dell VIRTUAL DISK SCSI 500GB
  System: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
  Java version: 7 update 4 x64
  Apache Cassandra version: 1.1.1

Cassandra server configuration:

```
heap size: 4 GB
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
         - seeds: "xxx.xxx.xxx.10,xxx.xxx.xxx.11"
listen_address: xxx.xxx.xxx.10
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_timeout_in_ms: 20000
endpoint_snitch: PropertyFileSnitch
```

cassandra-topology.properties

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.10=datacenter1:rack1
xxx.xxx.xxx.11=datacenter1:rack1
default=datacenter1:rack1
```

### Problem

I have ctreated keyspace and column family using CLI commands:

```
create keyspace testks with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy' and strategy_options = {datacenter1:2};
use testks;
create column family testcf;
```

Then I started my Java application, which inserts 50 000 000 rows to created column family using Hector client. Client is connected to node 1.
After about 30 seconds (160 000 rows were inserted) Cassandra server on node 1 throws an exception:

```
ERROR [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2012-06-13 10:26:38,393 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 134) Exception in thread Thread[COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR,5,main]
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Rename from c:\apache-cassandra\storage\commitlog\CommitLog-7345742389552.log to 7475933520374 failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:127)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.recycle(CommitLogSegment.java:204)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$2.run(CommitLogAllocator.java:166)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogAllocator.java:95)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Rename from c:\apache-cassandra\storage\commitlog\CommitLog-7345742389552.log to 7475933520374 failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:105)
    ... 5 more
```

Then, few seconds later Cassandra server on node 2 throws the same exception:

```
ERROR [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2012-06-14 10:26:44,005 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 134) Exception in thread Thread[COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR,5,main]
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Rename from c:\apache-cassandra\storage\commitlog\CommitLog-7320337904033.log to 7437675489307 failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:127)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.recycle(CommitLogSegment.java:204)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$2.run(CommitLogAllocator.java:166)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogAllocator.java:95)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Rename from c:\apache-cassandra\storage\commitlog\CommitLog-7320337904033.log to 7437675489307 failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:105)
    ... 5 more
```

After that, my application cannot insert any more data. Hector gets TimedOutException from Thrift:

```
Thread-4 HConnectionManager.java 306 012-06-14 10:12:56,034      HConnectionManager operateWithFailover      WARN    %Could not fullfill request on this host CassandraClient<xxx.xxx.xxx.10:9160-10> 
Thread-4 HConnectionManager.java 307 2012-06-14 10:12:56,034     HConnectionManager operateWithFailover      WARN    %Exception:  
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HTimedOutException: TimedOutException()
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:35)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:264)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
    at patrycjusz.nosqltest.db.cassandra.CassandraHectorDbAdapter.commitTransaction(CassandraDbAdapter.java:63)
    at patrycjusz.nosqltest.DbTest.insertData(DbTest.java:459)
    at patrycjusz.nosqltest.gui.InsertPanel.executeTask(NePanel.java:154)
    at patrycjusz.nosqltest.gui.InsertPanel$1.run(NePanel.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: TimedOutException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:20269)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:922)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:908)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:246)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:103)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:258)
    ... 8 more
```

How can I solve it? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Regards, Patrycjusz

Comment: Apache Cassandra version 1.1.1

Comment: Same issue with Java 1.6?  http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/install_rpm -- Java7 is not "recommended"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll run the tests on Java 1.6 u33 x64.

Comment: It's worth noting that running Cassandra on Windows is not really a good idea.

Comment: Last night I ran the tests without any errors. It seems that this bug is related to Java version I used. Problem doesn't occur when using Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 7 isn't fully supported by Apache Cassandra.  http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/install_rpm

> Java7 is not "recommended"

As you've found, going with 1.6 you have no issues...